# What are the advantages and limitations of using Qt for game development?

Tags: qt

I know there is already a thread asking for example 3d games written using Qt. What I'd like to have a discussion about is whether or not Qt is a good framework for game development.

In my experience Qt is a joy to work with and thanks to QML and QML/3d it's looking like it could be a viable framework for game development. The thought of using signals and slots for gamedev is exciting.

I'd like to hear some opinions on Qt in general as a game development platform. What are it's limitations? What are it's advantages?

Edit: I found an [official Qt game development forum](https://forum.qt.io/category/17/game-development).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the Game Development StackExchange. Generally, we discourage discussion style questions, as they are not the best fit for the Q&A format. We ask that you ask [Practical, answerable questions based on problems that you face](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @Noctrine Would a rewording be acceptable? I really just want to know the pros and cons of Qt for game development, if anyone has tried it.

Comment: There's an active [meta topic on the subject of pro/con questions](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/539/review-this-for-me-questions). In its current form, I think this question should be closed a "discussion" isn't really appropriate here.

Comment: I made a very comprehensive answer to a similar question on s.o. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905222/will-qt-be-a-good-choice-for-a-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used properly, Qt can be great for games.  It has good OpenGL support if you want hardware acceleration, and if you're dealing with 2D elements or custom widgets, the QPainter class and its friends have decent performance (just stay away from QPainter::SetOpacity, that'll kill your performance).

The other great thing about Qt for games is Qt Style Sheets.  You can create a custom look-and-feel for your GUI using a CSS-like syntax, so your game's GUI won't look like a boring gray platform-specific interface.

Comment: Well usually a game's buttons are just sprites/textures, but I suppose in an early prototype you could be using a toolkit's widgets

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with Qt and it is quite nice, defenitely OK for a not too complicated game, for a 2D game it would be perfect I'd say.

The pros I found:

- integrated translation
- simplicity when creating menus

The cons I've stumbled into:

- no draw calls from other threads than the main thread.
- complicated to debug signals

Comment: "no draw calls from other threads than the main thread" that's a limitation  of the way OpenGL contexts work, not Qt. Not sure about Direct3D though.

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is quite old, maybe this could still be interesting for some of you:
[V-Play](http://v-play.net/) is a cross platform game engine based on Qt.

It offers a wide range of components specialised for game development, monetization and social services.[API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html).

You can also have a look at some games that are already live in the App Stores in the showcase section of their homepage.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the guys behind V-Play)